# Multiple data attributes in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to set more than one data attribute with custom info inside of it. Unfortunately, this isn´t working:

```
    <p data={"Very important info"} onClick={this.accessAttributes}
data2={"A lot of important info"}></p>

accessAttributes = e =>{
ToggleFavorito = (e) =>{

  let data1=e.currentTarget.data;
  let data2=e.currentTarget.data2;
  console.log(data1, data2)

}
```

It returns "undefined".

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? What error do you get?

Comment: That data-2 is undefined.

Comment: You can't be using a - in React for a property.

Comment: Doesn´t work even if I change it to "data2"

Comment: Can you post the code where you're trying to access the props of `<p>`?

Comment: that is not a problem of react, `data-2` is not a valid name according to specs of data-attributes.

Comment: See updated question

Comment: data attr should be something like this => data-*, try rename data2 to data-2

Comment: it would be `e.target.attributes.data2`. to access i mean

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is to use data or data2 as normal html attributes, you can use

```
accessAttributes = e =>{
  let data1=e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data");
  let data2=e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data2")
  console.log(data1, data2)
}
```

If you wanted them as [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#JavaScript_access), you can use

```
<p data-one={"Very important info"} onClick={this.accessAttributes}
data-two={"A lot of important info"}></p>

accessAttributes = e =>{
  let data1=e.currentTarget.dataset.one
  let data2=e.currentTarget.dataset.two
  console.log(data1, data2)
}
```

By the way, If your `p` is in render, there is no content inside p to click. Or at least it should have a height and width.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  accessAttributes = e =>{
  let data1=e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data");
  let data2=e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data2")
    console.log(data1, data2)
  }
   
  accessAttributes2 = e =>{
  let data1=e.currentTarget.dataset.one;
  let data2=e.currentTarget.dataset.two;
  console.log(data1, data2)
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p data={"Very important info"} onClick={this.accessAttributes}
            data2={"A lot of important info"}>x</p>

        <p data-one={"Very important info"} onClick={this.accessAttributes2}
            data-two={"A lot of important info"}>y</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dataset api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Basically, you convert from `data-some-field` to `target.dataset.someField`, being `some-field` converted to camelCased `someField` (`target.dataset` is a map object with your properties you set in a props fashion style)

See this fiddle

```js
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

  accessAttributes(e){
    let data1 = e.target.dataset.value;
    let data2 = e.target.dataset.numberTwo;
    console.log(`data1: ${data1}`);
    console.log(`data2: ${data2}`);
}

    render() {
        return <p data-value={"Very important info"} onClick={this.accessAttributes}
data-number-two={"A lot of important info"}>P TAG!</p>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Keep in mind that by [data- naming conventions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) you cannot use numbers for naming your `data-` fields

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this I needed a way to pass any data attribute through to my component.

```
import Player from '../Player/Player';

<Player setup={
    {
        code: "<code>",
        type: "<type>"
    }
}/>
```

Component

```
import React from "react";

export default class Player extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const attributes = {
            className: 'media',
        }
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.props.setup)) {
            attributes[`data-${key}`] = value;
        }
        return (<div {...attributes}></div>);
    }
}
```

Dom output

```
<div class="media" data-code="<code>" data-type="<type>"></div>
```